# Unable to get Latitude/Longitude to change on Android app

Tags: android

Seem to be having some issues getting the longitude and latitude to change on my gps app I am making.  I am new to Android, and am not 100% sure I did it right.  I also want to note that I do NOT want to use listners for only when the location changes.  I specifically want it to update every 5 seconds as I have it in the thread.  I also don't seem to be retrieving any satellite data from the stuff I used below either.  I just keep writing an empty list to my log file.  Am I missing a permission or is the code just wrong?  All of the needed information is provided below.  Thanks.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize various GPS things
        location = new Location("now");
        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        gps = lm.getGpsStatus(null);

        // Create Entry List for later use
        entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        rows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();

        // Turn off Stop by default
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        button.setEnabled(false);

        // GPS enabled?
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

        backgroundThread.start();
    }

Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (keepGoing) {
                // timestamp
                long ts = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

                // set location
                location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true));

                // location stuff
                float ac = location.getAccuracy();
                double al = location.getAltitude();
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                double lon = location.getLongitude();
                DataEntry d = new DataEntry(ac, al, lat, lon);

                // satellite stuff
                List<GPSSatelliteEntry> GPSentries = new ArrayList<GPSSatelliteEntry>();
                Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats = gps.getSatellites();
                Iterator<GpsSatellite> satI = sats.iterator();
                while (satI.hasNext()) {
                    GpsSatellite item = (GpsSatellite) satI.next();
                    float az = item.getAzimuth();
                    float el = item.getElevation();
                    int p = item.getPrn();
                    float s = item.getSnr();

                    GPSSatelliteEntry temp = new GPSSatelliteEntry(az, el, p, s);
                    GPSentries.add(temp);
                }

                Entry en = new Entry(ts, d, GPSentries);
                entries.add(en);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); // 5000 ms
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            writeData();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLastKnownLocation only works if something on the device is generating the location updates.  If nothing on your phone has called requestLocationUpdates, then thye will never update in getLastKnownLocation.  The fix is to call requestLocationUpdates and either move your logic into those functions, or even ignore the calls to those functions but have them going off anyway.  Remember to unregister when you no longer want updates, like in onStop.